# How to Read a Specific sheet from an Excel File Using Django

Tags: python, django

I'm reading an xlsx file to store the data in the database. Everything is working correctly. But my question is that I want to read only one specific spreadsheet from the Excel file.

For example, a file can have multiple sheets like:

Sheet1, Sheet2 ...

I want to read data only from Sheet2 and store in database.

At the moment I'm doing it as follows:

```
imported_data = dataset.load(data.read(), format='xlsx')
```

However, this way it does not filter a specific sheet.

How can I do this?

After I put each line of sheet in database.

```
 for d in imported_data:
                    value = DataSheet(
                        x,
                        d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7], d[8], d[9], d[10], d[11],
                        d[12], d[13], d[14], d[15], d[16], d[17], d[18], d[19], d[20], d[21], d[22], d[23],
                        d[24], d[25], d[26], d[27]
                    )
                
                    value.save()
```

Comment: what packages are you using to load the dataset? Django isn't the problem here; it's whatever `dataset` is from. Please re-tag the question. Btw, the `d[0]` etc. can be simplified to `*d[:28]` I believe

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Read the target sheet from the excel file into a data-frame object
2. Write the data-frame to a `BytesIO` object (or an xlsx file)

**file.xlsx**

- Sheet1

  | This | is |
  | --- | --- |
  | number | 1 |
- Sheet2

  | While | this |
  | --- | --- |
  | is | 2nd |
- Sheet3

  | Here | lies |
  | --- | --- |
  | the | third |

Here is a solution using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import io

import pandas

with open('./file.xlsx', 'rb') as file_xlsx:  # In your case, this would be the <data.read()>
    data_frame = pandas.read_excel(file_xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet2')

    bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
    excel_writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(bytes_io, engine='openpyxl')

    data_frame.to_excel(excel_writer, index=False)

    excel_writer.save()  # Save the workbook
    bytes_io.seek(0)  # Seek back to the beginning of the file
```

Now, `bytes_io` contains the resulting bytes of the excel file with only the "Sheet2". This is the data that you need to store to the database.

To verify this, let's write it back to an xlsx file by accessing the `bytes_io.read()`.

```
with open('./file_updated.xlsx', 'wb') as file_xlsx_updated:
    file_xlsx_updated.write(bytes_io.read())
```

**file_updated.xlsx**

- Sheet1

  | While | this |
  | --- | --- |
  | is | 2nd |

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using tablib.Databook()

```
imported_data = tablib.Databook()  
imported_data.xlsx = data.read()
for dataset in imported_data.sheets():
    if dataset.title == 'name of the sheet':
       #do anything
```